# How to allow for ampersand in XMLtable()?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, xml

Starting with [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267868/how-to-convert-xml-entities-to-unicode-characters-with-read-only-access-in-ora), note that **while this works**:

```
with data as (
  select 'Hallöle sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina' str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || a.str || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
```

**… this fails** (note the addition of "**AT&T and AT & T**" to the string):

```
with data as (
  select 'Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina' str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || a.str || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
```

with **error message**:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use &amp;)
Error at line 2
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

How to fix?

---

First crude attempt(s):

```
replace('Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina', ' & ', ' and ')
```

While this works (at least for "AT & T", it would be desirable to **preserve the ampersand in the final output**…

Comment: @mustaccio I have no control over the string ("Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina"); I can only parse it, and xmltable() does take care of the latter special characters, but not of the ampersand characters.

Comment: Nowadays with UTF-8 HTLM entities are not really state-of-the-art anymore. [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) says: *It is almost always preferable to use an encoding that allows you to represent characters in their normal form, rather than using named character references or numeric character references.

Using escapes can make it difficult to read and maintain source code, and can also significantly increase file size.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `'&#38;\2'` as replacement string, backreferencing the 2nd ( ) group:**

```
with data as (
  select 'Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina' str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || regexp_replace(a.str,'(&)([^#])','&38;\2') || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly told you to use `&amp;`.

```
with data as (
  select 'Hallöle AT&amp;T and AT &amp; T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina' str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || a.str || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
;

STR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
STR2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hallöle AT&amp;T and AT &amp; T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina
Hallöle AT&T and AT & T slovenĈina Hallöle slovenđina
```

Update (will not work for other special characters such as `&gt;`):

```
with data as (
  select regexp_replace('Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina', '(&)([^#])', '\1amp;\2') str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || a.str || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
;

STR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
STR2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hallöle AT&amp;T and AT &amp; T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina
Hallöle AT&T and AT & T slovenĈina Hallöle slovenđina
```

Comment: I have no control over the string ("Hallöle AT&T and AT & T sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina"); I can only parse it, and xmltable() does take care of the latter special characters, but not of the ampersand characters.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Then just use some regexp. See my update for example. It is not complete, works on this example, but will not work if you have other special characters like `&gt;`. Unfortunately this is something you need to handle, your input does not follow the standard, your `&`s should be `&amp;`s in the input.

Comment: I just posted an (incomplete) answer with a regex which works; I only need to find a way to get the ampersand in the replacement string - without being prompted for a value.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty That is because `&` is a special character marking a substitution variable in sqlplus or SQL Developer. Use `set define off` to disable that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use build-in function [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100):

```
with data as (
  select 'Hallöle sloven&#264;ina Hallöle sloven&#273;ina' str from dual
)
select a.str, b.str2
from data a, xmltable( '/'
  passing xmltype( '<dat>' || DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(a.str,0) || '</dat>' )
  columns
   str2 varchar2(4000) path '/dat'
) b
```

Function [HTF.ESCAPE_SC](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_htf.htm#ARPLS70276) should also work.

Comment: That's the wrong string (cf. original question).